# Is this grammatically correct? "Martin heard footsteps rushing towards his office."

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct?

"Martin heard footsteps rushing towards his office."

I think something's missing between *footsteps* and *rushing*.
By adding *were*, I believe the sentence becomes grammatically perfect, but while writing novel where authors loves to break rules in order to maintain fluency, the sentence breaks the fluency of the paragraph.
So I wanna keep this sentence as this is in my novel if it's really grammatically correct.

Comment: "were" would make it ungrammatical. He could have written: the sound of footsteps, but chose not to. The fluency is all there as is.

Comment: With "Martin heard footsteps were rushing towards his office", you would have two independent clauses, sharing *footsteps*, the direct object of the first and subject of the second. That's an error. Keep it as is :)

Comment: your question in the title - my sense: it is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of **rushing** doesn't seem right to me, because **rushing** is not something you can hear.

I would use a description that *can* be heard, which itself implies rushing.

> Martin heard footsteps pounding towards his office.

Comment: Yes, I thought that at first too, but then realised that you can sometimes hear footsteps running or rushing toward you.

Comment: @RobynSimpson wouldn't that be "the sound of running footsteps"?

Comment: Yes, I entirely agree with you, but by googling it I saw that many authors have used poetic license. I'm upvoting your answer.

Comment: @RobynSimpson Except that with poetic licence, it's quite correct to say you can hear "rushing footsteps"—which is denied in the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: @JasonBassford someone downvoted this answer, but the question was about grammatical usage and not poetic licence. Poetic licence is never "quite correct", by definition.

Comment: @WeatherVane Would somebody write such a phrase outside of a narrative in which poetic license wouldn't be part of acceptable style? (In other words, although I would not use **rushing** in that sentence if I put it in an essay—I would not put it in an essay in the first place. I'd only put it in a book and, in that context, it would be probably be fine—unless it didn't match the style of the rest of the book.)

Comment: Actually, I wonder (if I'm being literal) if footsteps *can* pound (or do anything.). It makes sense that *feet* can pound, but I'm not sure about footsteps. I don't think a [footstep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/footsteps) can be an agent of an action. I know it's fine, but isn't that poetic license too?

Comment: @JasonBassford if feel you know better please post your answer explaining why poetic licence is grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

Adding "were" to this sentence would not make sense.  To my ears the original sentence sounded a little strange, but I did a google search of "heard footsteps rushing towards" (with the quotation marks), and it says it found "About 1,830 results".
 So yes, keep this sentence as is.

Comment: The exact number of results found for that search is closer to [61](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDviK.png) or less, if you exclude more of the duplicates. Google's estimates are [almost always wrong](https://searchengineland.com/why-google-cant-count-results-properly-53559), sometimes (at least in my experience) off by hundreds of thousands. Thus, it's not a good idea to use Google's estimate as proof.

Comment: However, *Martin heard footsteps* ***that were*** *rushing towards his office* would be fine. Although, "Hey, somebody told me that footsteps were rushing towards his door." "Yes, I heard that too. I heard (someone say) footsteps were rushing towards his door." ;) So, it might actually be fine in a very specific context.

Answer (score 1):

The footsteps are what you hear, rushing describes what they are doing. To my ears "heard footsteps rushing" sounds a little odd, but that's just me. In addition to a general google search, you can look at examples in published books, which have presumably passed through the hands of at least one editor.

"heard footsteps rushing" is less common than "heard footsteps pounding", but it is in plenty of modern published works. Here are just two examples:

[The Battle for Fallujah](https://books.google.com/books?id=m7ctAQAAIAAJ&q=%22footsteps+rushing%22&dq=%22footsteps+rushing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixzYyS5eLbAhUaFjQIHY-RBo8Q6AEIVDAI), by Vincent Foulk

> The Marines heard footsteps rushing up to the door, and one instinctively pointed his M16 at the entrance

[True North](https://books.google.com/books?id=w5kIjSg9VpIC&pg=PA234&dq=%22footsteps+rushing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixzYyS5eLbAhUaFjQIHY-RBo8Q6AEINDAC) by Pete Catalano

> Finally I heard his voice getting closer, and the sound of his footsteps rushing down the hall

Comment: It seems to me that "he heard footsteps coming toward his office" or "...coming quickly toward his office" would be clearer.

Comment: @tautophile and less descriptive (for the OPs novel).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think footsteps rush. They pound, they patter, etc. Rushing to me seems like water, wind, people, actual things that move, not sounds.